Train a QdrantEmbeddingRetriever with custom model
Using haystack-1x, I was able to create an EmbeddingRetriever and train it with a custom model as follows:
retriever = EmbeddingRetriever( document_store = <my_doc_store>,
                                embedding_model = <some_model>,
                                model_format = <some_format>,
                                use_gpu = true,
                                max_seq_len = 512 )

dataset = compile_training_data()

retriever.train( training_data = dataset,
                 n_epochs = 10 )

retriever.save( <path to some dir> )

I cannot seem to find a way to do the same using QdrantEmbeddingRetriever now that haystack 2x has removed the EmbeddingRetriever.
How can I train an embedding retriever using my own model?

I answered on the Discord thread you created...

Thank you @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87! I'm not a big fan of discord channels for dev questions and kinda gave up after receiving a response from an ai bot. Please feel free to post your answer here too with an example.

Copied from Discord:
In short, as you can understand from the migration guide (https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/migration#rag-pipeline),
in Haystack 2.x, the concepts of Embedder and Retriever have been separated.
(in 1.x, they were both part of the EmbeddingRetriever abstraction)
Speaking of model training, Haystack 2.x removed support for this.
If you need to train an embedding model, you can use Sentence Transformers and then load the obtained model in Haystack.
